# Need Syncfusion.OcrProcessor.Base.dll assembly reference

Tags: c#, tesseract, desktop-application, syncfusion, python-tesseract

I am using Tesseract in my c# Windows Form Application in which I want to extract text from PDF file so we need **Syncfusion.OcrProcessor.Base.dll** for doing this. Please help me find this reference. I am following this article: [OCR syncfusion](https://www.syncfusion.com/blogs/post/Optical-Character-Recognition-in-PDF-Using-Tesseract-Open-Source-Engine.aspx)

Comment: Well, you'll most likely need to buy (or download the trial version, or use the community-license if you're eligible) of the [Syncfusion Essential PDF](https://www.syncfusion.com/products/file-formats/pdf) that is linked in the blog post you provided.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to getting the Syncfusion.OCRProcessor.Base.dll assemblies. First, you can install the file formats build, then automatically installed the Syncfusion.OCRProcessor.Base.dll assembly  in your machine. You can add the following assemblies as references in the OCR application.

1. Syncfusion.Compression.Base.dll
2. Syncfusion.Pdf.Base.dll
3. Syncfusion.OCRProcessor.Base.dll

File format link : https://www.syncfusion.com/products/file-formats/pdf

Second, You can download the Nuget packages from the following link, and then get the Syncfusion.OCRProcessor.Base.dll. Please find the Nuget packages link here:

Nuget Package link : http://nuget.syncfusion.com/package/windows-forms